# getting invalied difference between two DateTime picker using 'momentjs'

Tags: jquery, momentjs, datetimepicker

I have two DateTime pickers which is recodeStartTime and recodeEndTime, I want to show the total hours between the above times using moment.js. However, when I try to retrieve the difference using the following:

```
var calculateTime = function () {
    var startTime = $('#recordStartTime').val();
    var endTime   = $('#recordEndTime').val();
    var totalTime = moment.utc(moment(endTime,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(startTime,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss");
    $('#recordRegularHours').val(totalTime);
};
```

> Ex: recodeStartTime = 2017-09-01 08:40 AM , recodeEndTime   =
>   2017-09-01 05:45 PM
>
> result : 21:05:00

It is returning the invalid time difference. How do I get the difference in hours between two Moments?

Comment: Your code give `21:05:00` for `recodeStartTime = 2017-09-01 08:40 AM , recodeEndTime = 2017-09-01 05:45 PM`, what is exactly your issue?

Comment: The difference should be like 09:05:00 @VincenzoC

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [`duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) from the output of moment [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), then you can use [moment-duration-format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/plugins/duration-format/) plug-in. The plug-in adds the [`format`](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format#template) method to duration, so you can use `format('HH:mm:ss')` to get the output in the desired format (`09:05:00` in your case).

Here a working sample:

```js
var calculateTime = function () {
  var startTime = $('#recordStartTime').val();
  var endTime   = $('#recordEndTime').val();

  var diff = moment(endTime,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A").diff(moment(startTime,"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A"));
  var dur = moment.duration(diff);
  var totalTime = dur.format('HH:mm:ss')
  $('#recordRegularHours').val(totalTime);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/1.3.0/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="recordStartTime" value="2017-09-01 08:40 AM">
<input type="text" id="recordEndTime" value="2017-09-01 05:45 PM">

<input type="text" id="recordRegularHours" readonly>

<button type="button" onclick="calculateTime()">Calulate Diff</button>
```

Note that you have to use `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A"` instead of `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"` to parse correctly input like `2017-09-01 08:40 AM`.

If you don't want to add moment-duration-format plug-in, you can use duration getters ([`hours()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/hours/), [`minutes()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/minutes/), [`seconds()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/seconds/)).